# Avoid Horizontal ScrollView in titanium

Tags: android, ios, titanium, scrollview

How to avoid horizontal scorll in `Titanium Appcelerator`. Even though `scrollType` attribute is mentioned as vertical in `ScrollView` its working both vertical and horizontal in `Titanium`. How can I avoid horizontal type?

*Registration.xml*

```
<ScrollView class="scroll" top="8%">

</ScrollView>
```

*Registration.tss*

```
".scroll":{
     scrollType:'vertical'
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

You could try to explicitly set the contentWidth of the scrollView to '100%' or Ti.UI.FILL. This should prevent the view from enabling horizontal scrolling. Additionally you should keep the scrollType declaration to 'vertical'.